# Optimal method for combining graph data? (neo4j)

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, corruption

I had a neo4j graph database get corrupted- some portion of nodes and relationships were destroyed. The most recent backup I had was several weeks old.

The corrupted graph still has usable data that I would like to reconcile with the old backup I have.

Is there an optimal way to go about combining the usable data from the corrupted graph with the old backup I have?

Thanks.

Comment: How did the data get corrupted?  How do you know it's in the store still at all?

Comment: The instance was running at GrapheneDB.com on one of their sandbox instances. A few days ago they had same machines go down due to a hardware issue (I don't have all the details). They put what they could back up within several hours. Most of my queries were broken until the index was rebuilt, once they were, I realized a number of nodes/relationships simply were no longer there. There is definitely still usable data in the graph, just not the complete graph.